# RVM not keeping ruby version

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have to keep setting my ruby version.  How to I make sure RVM keeps the version I need?

When I do `rvm list`, I get:

```
   ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.4.4 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.5.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.5.2 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.5.3 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.6.1 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.6.3 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.6.5 [ x86_64 ]
```

So then I do `rvm use 2.6.5` and it changes to 2.6.5, but as soon as I close and open the terminal again, I whichs back to 2.6.3. What am I doing wrong? I set the default 2.6.5, it just does not seem to listen.

Comment: This question is wrongly marked as a duplicate: the default is clearly set correctly, visible from the output from `rvm list`. You should check if there is a `.rvmrc` or `.ruby-version` file in the directory which will automatically set the ruby version regardless of the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `rvm list` we clearly see the default is set correctly (marked with the asterisk), so check your current folder for the presence of a `.rvmrc` or `.ruby-version` file which will overrule the rvm default version.

Comment: .ruby-version file was the issue and Thank you! for looking carefully

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: As OP stated, they were correctly setting the default but having it overriden by a .ruby-version file, see above and ignore below

You're telling RVM to use 2.6.5, not setting it as the default.

Try:

```
rvm --default use 2.6.5
```

See "[The Basics of RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/basics)" for more information.

Comment: We clearly see the default _is_ set correctly, marked with the asterisk, so this is not correct/helpful.

Comment: As @nathanvda stated, my default was set correctly, the issue is a .ruby-version file.